# Cannot create index on view with User Defined Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, view, user-defined-functions

In SQL Server 2005, I'm trying to use a User Defined Function in a indexed view that will be used in a full-text index. I have been able to get the UDF to work with a stored procedure and the view in question. But, when I try to create an index on the view I get the following error...

**Cannot create index on view "DevDatabase.dbo.View_PersonSearch" because function "dbo.GetCurrentImage" referenced by the view performs user or system data access.**

I am stumped by this. Below is an example of what I am trying to do. Am I missing something or is this even possible?

*User Defined Function*

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCurrentImage](@Person_ID int) 
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Img_ID int

    SET @Img_ID = (**sql that selects image** )

    RETURN @Img_ID

END
GO
```

*View with index creation*

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[View_PersonSearch]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  Person_ID,
            (**Select fields to search on**) AS SearchArea,
            dbo.GetCurrentImage(Person_ID) AS FK_Img_ID
FROM    dbo.Person
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Index_Person_ID ON [View_PersonSearch](Person_ID)
GO
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this page](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/28/sql-server-restrictions-of-views-t-sql-view-limitations/):

> Any functions referenced in an indexed
>   view must be deterministic;
>   deterministic functions return the
>   same value each time they’re invoked
>   with the same arguments.

GetCurrentImage is not deterministic with respect to its parameters - it uses a select, which means the results may change as the data changes - so any view using it cannot be indexed.

Comment: ahhh...I get it now. Thank you for bringing that into the light for me.

Comment: I, too, would actually like to know how you overcame this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There's a recent documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2016

Under `Additional Requirements` it says: `The data access property of a user-defined function must be NO SQL, and external access property must be NO.`

You can check you UDF with the following statement

```sql
    SELECT ObjectPropertyEx(Object_Id('dbo.GetCurrentImage'), N'IsDeterministic') AS deterministic, 
        ObjectPropertyEx(Object_Id('dbo.GetCurrentImage'), N'IsPrecise') AS precise, 
        ObjectPropertyEx(Object_Id('dbo.GetCurrentImage'), N'IsSystemVerified') AS verified, 
        ObjectPropertyEx(Object_Id('dbo.GetCurrentImage'), N'UserDataAccess') AS UserDataAccess,
        ObjectPropertyEx(Object_Id('dbo.GetCurrentImage'), N'SystemDataAccess') AS SystemDataAccess;
```

The first three should give `1`, the last two must be `0` for a function to be used in an indexed view.